# how to store multiple match words in an array in php regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

i want to match different words of an html page in php like this & but have problem in these words are in same sentence!!

BOTH Eg 1 and Eg 2. Are in same page !!!

**suppose i have these lines**

```
  Eg 1. $html="
    write('A')</script>
    write('B')</script>
    write('C')</script>
    write('D')</script>
    write('E')</script>";
```

preg_match_all('/write(\'([A-Z])')</script>/',$html,$match);
i will match A,B,C,D,E but......& **how to store multiple matches ??**

another same as this

also i want to matched all these  "Numbers" in this code

```
Eg 2. $html="
    write(33453)</script>
    write(6987)</script>
    write(4544)</script>
    write(345)</script>
    write(7876)</script> ";
```

preg_match_all('/write((.*?))</script>/',$html,$matches);

my question is how could i store multiple matches as you seen in eg.1 and eg.2 and then echo it combined like in 3rd output below:(

```
A-33453
B-6987
C-4544
D-345
E-7876
```

& also i want help for how could i select randomly a Number in Eg 2. like 345 from array ????

Comment: Questions asking for code often beneift from showing a few prior attempts and effort.

Comment: Neither of your RegExps will work, because you didn't escape the parens to be literally `\(` matched. And `preg_match_all()` already returns an array. Please avoid "plz" nagging.

Comment: sorry for that .. my intention is not for you to order !! but i want help for the given problem of mine ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = <<<EOF
    write('A')</script>
    write('B')</script>
    write('C')</script>
    write('D')</script>
    write('E')</script>

    write(33453)</script>
    write(6987)</script>
    write(4544)</script>
    write(345)</script>
    write(7876)</script>
EOF;

preg_match_all('~write\(\'([A-Z])\'\)</script>~', $html, $match1);
preg_match_all('~write\(([0-9]+)\)</script>~', $html, $match2);

foreach ($match1[1] as $i => $char)
    echo "$char-{$match2[1][$i]}\n";
```

Comment: bro its works ... but not giving proper output :( could you give me another method to do this and also bro want to ask that how could i select randomly a match from all the matches ??? like 345 form all the matches like 33453,6987,.so on  :D

Comment: It does for me. At least for this sample.

Comment: ok thnxx it works bro but also tell how could i randomly select 1 match from all matches??? like in eg.2 345 selected at random & then store it in $var ???

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting any array results, because your regex is wrong:

```
preg_match_all('/write(\'[A-Z]\')</script>/',$html,$match);
```

The `(` and `)` do not match literal parentheses. They need to be escaped as `\(` and `\)`.

Within you also have an unescaped delimiter `/` right before `script`. Which needs an escaping backslash as well. Enable [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/error_reporting) whenever something isn't working.

Only then will `$match[0]` contain anything. And you probably want to add capture parens then around `([A-Z])` to get a usable `$match[1]`.

Comment: ok bro i corrected my regex but my question is how could i store multiple matches as you seen in eg.1 and eg.2 and then echo it combined like in 3rd output :(

Comment: Your `foreach` attempts so far? (SO is not a tutoring service. That's all kinda trivial.)